# Ant getting nullpointerexception after tests

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am having a problem trying to run junit tests in ant with forkmode set to anything else but "perTest"(the default)

Whenever I am running the tests, right as it is executing the last test(it might actually happen after it is finished, but thats the order the output appears on the screen) it generates the following exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter.getHostname(XMLJUnitResultFormatter.java:165)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter.startTestSuite(XMLJUnitResultFormatter.java:141)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.fireStartTestSuite(JUnitTestRunner.java:822)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:519)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1165)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:988)
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Tests FAILED (crashed)

Here is the junit line of my build.xml:

```
            <junit fork="yes" forkmode="perBatch" printsummary="yes" haltonerror="false" haltonfailure="false">
```

I am running ant 1.9, any suggestions on what could be causing this?

I should add that this does not happen if I have it set to perTest, but then the tests take forever.

Comment: your hostname set correctly on the machine and can be resolved?

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing dig `hostname` and it came back with an answer.  Also, if that was the cause then why would it work when it isn't forked?

Comment: Run `ant -diagnostics` and tell us the value of the following properties: `ant.version` and `java.runtime.version`.

Comment: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
java.runtime.version=1.7.0_51-b13